# Is there a way to run a shutdown function when my task killed by taskmgr on windows using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can run a func if user use "CTRL+C" or "X" but if user try to kill my program using task manager on windows, is there a way to run a last function? Im using python 3.3 and windows 7. I tried atexit,signal modules but they dont work. Cant i stop taskmgr?

Answer (score 0):

Yea i think so.

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, custom_func)
```

More information after googling for "Python windows catch process termination"
http://danielkaes.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/how-to-catch-kill-events-with-python/

But if the signal is a kill-no-matter-what signal, then you will not be able to interrupt that call with a function that takes time because well, it's a forced termination -9 in unix i think and that will just drop whatever processing power the process. Correct me if i'm wrong but it's not possible to abort or call a function if it's forced?

Comment: The key question here is whether taskmgr tries some kind of "soft" termination before `TerminateProcess` (Maybe it posts `WM_QUIT` first?). There is no way to handle `TerminateProcess`, but you can handle `WM_QUIT` (though not with `signal`, probably)

Comment: @AntonKovalenko I think you're right - IIRC, you can handle an "End Task" (SIGTERM) (which gives grace for cleanup), but if a user does an "End Process" (which should only really be required for ill-behaving programs), then you're stuffed...

Comment: Exactly, WM_QUIT (SIGTERM) can be responded to and thus given a grace period like shown above. However a "End Process" (forced termination of process meaning no more processing power is allowed for the PID and thus droped from the stack) is not possible at all..
But as @JonClements mentioned, this should only need to be done on ill-behaving applications (even endless loops might not even require "End Process" in most cases).